# Seeking Guidance on Creating Sample Data for AI Business Use Case

Tags: dataset, data

Subject: Seeking Guidance on Creating Sample Data for AI Business Use Case

Dear StackExhange Family

I am currently working on an AI project aimed at providing AI embaded solutions to HealthCare, Banking, Finance, HR. As part of this endeavor as an Project Manager, I am in the process of generating sample data that accurately represents our business use case.

Given your expertise in the above mentioned Sectors, I was wondering if Someone could offer some guidance on the best practices for creating sample data for an AI-driven application. Specifically, we are looking to.

Any insights or suggestions you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Your expertise in this area would be invaluable to me.

Thank you so much for considering my request. I'm open to further discussions if you have more insights to share.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Tarun

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There isn't really any one answer to "how do I generate data".  What you need to generate depends on what your real data looks like and what you are trying to wring out of it.  If I had to give general advice without knowing anything about the problem, I think the best I could do is 1) if you have access to a large enough set of real data, sample from that.  2) If you don't, generate something that looks like it.  As it stands, giving a useful answer to this question is basically impossible.